# Create Shader (or Material) in Unity to create to intersect objects and make the intersection transparent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, shader

I'm working on a Unity project and I need to create a shader (or ShaderGraph) that allows me to cut one object using another object's geometry. The desired effect is to make the intersection area between these objects transparent, as if one object has cut into the other.

The effect is like a controlled fade as I can cut the objects as the intersection keeps going.

I would appreciate any guidance, code examples, or shader graph setups that could help me achieve this effect using Unity's shader system.

Thank you for your expertise and assistance!

I've tried some ShaderGraphs ([like this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uyw5yBFEoXo)) and tried to use the simple material intersection.